# redirect after form submit jquery

Tags: jquery, html, redirect

I have to submit a form with target = _blank and redirect the page to other.

HTML

```
<form id="registration_form" name="registration_form" method="post" action="actionurl" target="_blank">
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
   $('#registration_form').submit( function(e)
   {
      var flag=validate();
      if(flag)
          $(location).attr('href',redirectionurl);
      return flag;
   });

   $("#submit").click(function(){
      $('#registration_form').submit(); // this triggers the submit event
   });
});
```

If i change the button type to SUBMIT form submitting as per validation flag but redirection doesn't work.

If i use BUTTON instead of submit redirection takes place but form not submitting.

Where i have been wrong. Help.

Thank you.

Comment: Since the submit makes a round trip to the server , wouldn't it be more logical to make this redirection on the server side?

Comment: A standard form is normally a full request.  If the form is submitted then the page will reload and your redirect won't work reliably, since the new page will load.  You need to override the default behavior and send the form data using an Ajax request if you want to add additional logic in (you can't work after a standard submit without tricks).  It sounds like you're effectively recreating default behavior though...so the server side code should just serve the new page and validation should be done before the submit (and then your job is done).  Otherwise you'll need to do some reading

Comment: Depends on the server side language you are using. But i mean if you are submitting that means you have some sort of a block handling this submitt. You can just redirect at the end of this block. For exemple in asp.net there is something like `Response.Redirect` which will do the trick. I mean javascript is usefull if you dont want to make any request to the server, but since you are submitting the form there is no reason to make this redirection in javascript imho.

Comment: @MattWhipple, i should generate a pdf after submitting the form and redirect to the other page. so i cannot use ajax

Comment: @smk3108 PDFs and ajax are not mutually exclusive.  Right now you're attempting to do ajax style behavior without the ajax request.  Are you looking to have a page and a PDF open at the same time?  If not: you should just be validating before submit and then doing a full request.  If so: a simple solution would be to return the page with a call to open the PDF in a second window within the returned page, or you can do more on the front end but it sounds like you'd need more research for that approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do it in the hard way, since you define the target as _blank, but you DO submit the forum later, so i suggest you to do the validation on your server side and not on the jquery. the html code should look like that:

```
<form id="registration_form" name="registration_form" method="post" action="actionurl" target="_blank">
    <input type=hidden name="flag_input" value="false">
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
   $('#registration_form').submit( function(e)
   {
      var flag=validate();
      if(flag)
          $("#flag_input").val("true")
   });

   $("#submit").click(function(){
      $('#registration_form').submit(); 
   });
});
```

And then the server get the flag_input - if its true, it will redirect, if not, the user will have to fill the forum again. if you don't want redirect at all, you can use ajax.

**EDIT:**
and on the server side:(i don't know what langues you use but the basic is like that:)

if (flag_input==true) - generate PDF and redirect to X

else - redirect to Y(the forum page)

Let me know if that helped.
Goodluck!

Comment: i need to generate a pdf on form submit in the new tab and redirect the form page to other page. how to do it

Comment: ok, so you can use this code, and on the server side:(i don't know what langues you use but the basic is like that:)
if (flag_input==true)-redirect to X, else redirect to Y(i edited the answer)